# get list of bugzilla users for domain using bugziila api with codeigniter/zend lib?

Tags: codeigniter, zend-framework, bugzilla

i used this one but dont success login 
http://petehowe.co.uk/2010/example-of-calling-the-bugzilla-api-using-php-zend-framework/

This is my code
i didn't get echo 'ASDASD'; o/p in browser so problm in User.login

```
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eventBot\system\libraries\Zend\XmlRpc\Client.php';
echo "123";
$oClient = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://info.mydomainname.com:8080/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi');
echo "hello";
$oHttpClient = new Zend_Http_Client();
echo "123";
$oHttpClient->setCookieJar();

$oClient->setHttpClient($oHttpClient);

$aResponse = $oClient->call('User.login', array(array(
'login'    => 'myloginname@domainname',
'password' => 'mypassword',
'remember' => 1
)));
echo "ASDASD";
echo "$aResponse";
$aResponse = $oClient->call('Bug.create', array(array(
'product'     => "My Product",
'component'   => "My Component",
'summary'     => "This is the summary of the bug I'm creating",
'version'     => "unspecified",
'description' => "This is a description of the bug",
'op_sys'      => "All",
'platform'    => "---",
'priority'    => "P5",
'severity'    => "Trivial"
)));
$iBugId = $aResponse['id'];

$aResponse = $oClient->call('User.logout');

echo "ddfgfd";
```